# AWQL: Including device type in PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT results in less zero impression data?

Tags: python, api, google-ads-api

I've found some discrepancies in the PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT.

So before i post my test script and give some explanation i want to ask my questions:

- Why does AdWords behave like that?
- Is this behaviour normal or is it a bug?

Here is my little test script in Python to query AdWords shopping data (product groups) via AWQL and store the results as CSV:

```
from googleads import AdWordsClient

startdate = '20150801'
enddate = '20151130'
ADWORDS_API_VERSION = 'v201509'

client = AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage('adwords.yaml')
client.client_customer_id = 'XXX-XXX-XXXX'
report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version=ADWORDS_API_VERSION)

queries = {
    # (1) 
    'product_groups_without_device_split': (
        "SELECT CampaignName, CampaignId, AdGroupName, AdGroupId, "
        "ProductGroup, Impressions, Clicks, Conversions "
        "FROM PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT "
        "WHERE CampaignStatus IN ['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'] "
        "AND AdGroupStatus IN ['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'] "
        "AND PartitionType = UNIT AND Impressions > 0 "
        "DURING %s,%s"
    ),
    # (2) 
    'product_groups_without_device_split_zero_impressions': (
        "SELECT CampaignName, CampaignId, AdGroupName, AdGroupId, "
        "ProductGroup "
        "FROM PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT "
        "WHERE CampaignStatus IN ['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'] "
        "AND AdGroupStatus IN ['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'] "
        "AND PartitionType = UNIT AND Impressions = 0 "
        "DURING %s,%s"
    ),
    # (3)
    'product_groups': (
        "SELECT CampaignName, CampaignId, AdGroupName, AdGroupId, "
        "ProductGroup, Device, Impressions, Clicks, Conversions "
        "FROM PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT "
        "WHERE CampaignStatus IN ['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'] "
        "AND AdGroupStatus IN ['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'] "
        "AND PartitionType = UNIT AND Impressions > 0 "
        "DURING %s,%s"
    ),
    # (4)
    'product_groups_zero_impressions': (
        "SELECT CampaignName, CampaignId, AdGroupName, AdGroupId, "
        "ProductGroup, Device "
        "FROM PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT "
        "WHERE CampaignStatus IN ['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'] "
        "AND AdGroupStatus IN ['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'] "
        "AND PartitionType = UNIT AND Impressions = 0 "
        "DURING %s,%s"
    )
}

for name, awqlQueryTpl in queries.iteritems():
    awqlQuery = awqlQueryTpl % (startdate, enddate)
    with open(name+'.csv', 'w') as file_:
        report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(awqlQuery, 'CSV', file_,
            skip_report_header=True, skip_column_header=False,
            skip_report_summary=True)
```

(sensible data was edited out...)

Some explanation for the queries:

1. This first query includes statistic data but is without device split. Zero impressions can not be returned when statistic attributes (like impressions, clicks etc.) are selected!
2. This query doesn't include statistic data so i can get the missing data with zero impressions. No device split here.
3. This query includes statistic data and the data is splitted by devicetype. Zero impressions can not be returned here.
4. This query is without statistic data but with device type split. Only zero impression data is returned here

I combined the results of query 1+2 (=Case A) and query 3+4 (=Case B).
For case B i merged the data that was splitted by device type. So in comparison this result and result of (A) should be identical - but it is not!
Although the statistic data in both cases match, the difference is to be found in the zero impression data - which in (A) has more than 900 entries more than in B.

When i query without device but with including zero impressions (4) i get also campaigns that have zero impressions and are paused (which is what i want). But when i query with device (3) i don't get that campaigns at all...

I already proofed it all twice: that i did not make an error when merging and comparing the data. And i did the same test with data from the `KEYWORD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` and there were absolutely no issues!

I hope this is enough information to get some help here...

See my questions above.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution is to add `include_zero_impressions=True` to the DownloadReportWithAwql() function and remove `impressions=0` from the query:

```
for name, awqlQueryTpl in queries.iteritems():
    awqlQuery = awqlQueryTpl % (startdate, enddate)
    with open(name+'.csv', 'w') as file_:
        report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(awqlQuery, 'CSV', file_,
            skip_report_header=True, skip_column_header=False,
            skip_report_summary=True, include_zero_impressions=True)
```

I thought that using impressions=0 and impressions>0 in the query itself has the same effect but it seems my expectation was wrong.